# Magento URL redirection to categories based on customer login

Tags: magento

I need to redirect URL for particular user for example if men login the site must redirect to men category and if women login the site must redirect to women category . here following code i have used for redirection .

if(men)

$this->_redirect('men');

else

$this->_redirect('women');

can anyone explain me what i did wrong? above code is not working for me.

thanks 
Prakash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `Mage_Customer_AccountController::_loginPostRedirect()` method in order to redirect wherever you want after login.

If in case Men & Women are customer  groups then you can easily redirect them to any page you like using the following ready made extension:
http://www.magepsycho.com/custom-login-redirect-pro.html

Cheers!

Comment: Nope. I have posted either approach: to develop a module based on Account Controller Overriding or to use ready made solution.

Comment: Haha no problems, just poking fun :)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really sure how to answer this question.

What you have posted isn't really code. It isn't valid PHP.

In addition, what you are trying to achieve has no easy solution.

If you are new to learning programming, I would honestly recommend against starting with Magento. Magento is a very powerful platform, but the concepts and software behind it are very complicated.

I would recommend learning as much as you can about PHP/MySQL independently of Magento before trying to build with this platform.

Comment: Well, fair enough, but you have to assume then that in the case of "if (men)" men is defined as a constant, otherwise it would always return false. There's no indication of where or the context in which this code is used, and at first glance it looked like a blend of pseudo code and something copied from somewhere else.